# Extra characters ('.') appended to data from multiple files while writing to .csv file with python2 script

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to make a relatively simple script in python2 which crawls through multiple .out files in a directory and extracts some data.
The data is then written to a .csv file along with an identifier.

My issue is that a seemingly random '.' or '..' is appended to the end of the data string.

Here is my code (I know this is horrible to look at, sorry in advance) :

```
import os
import string
import time
import sys
import csv

input = raw_input
location = input('Set directory path: ')
os.makedirs(location+'/outputs/')
print "Created output directory."
print "Waiting for archiving to finish..."
forCall = "cd "+location+" && mv *.out outputs/"
os.system(forCall)
time.sleep(1)
print "Archived output files."

newLocation = location+"/outputs/"


def checker(filein, bondlength):
    o = open("results.csv", "a")
    with open(filein) as curFile:
        for line in curFile:
            if "SCF Done:" in line:
                var = line
                var = filter(lambda x: x.isdigit() or x == '-' or x == '.', var)
                var = var[1:-2] # slices the first '-' and two trailing '.'

                bondlength = ''.join(bondlength.split())
                bondlength = bondlength[:-4] # slices .out from 'bondlength.out'
                o.write(var+';'+bondlength+'\n')
    o.close()

for filename in os.listdir(newLocation):
    fileLocation = newLocation+filename
    checker(fileLocation, filename)

datacsv = csv.reader(open('results.csv'), delimiter=";")
sortedData = sorted(datacsv, key=lambda row: row[1], reverse=False)

with open('sortedData.csv', 'wb') as csv_file:
    wr = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=";")
    wr.writerows(sortedData)
```

The line in the .out file that I'm interested in looks like this:

> SCF Done:  E(RB+HF-LYP) =  -107.450926197     A.U. after    5 cycles

Now I need to get the value of E(whatever computational method was used) for each .out file and append it to a .csv file with 2 columns: one for the energy and one for the bond length (multiplied by 10^3, but that doesn't really matter now), which is the name of the .out file (ex. 1036.out).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your approach to extracting the data - filtering out characters that are not digits, dashes or dots from your example line would result in `--107.450926197..5` - the first dash comes from the `HF-LYP` part, the trailing 5 comes from the `5 cycles` and the two dots preceding it come from `A.U.`. When you slice out the first and last characters of the substring you'll therefore get `-107.450926197..`.

What I'd suggest instead is to find the number by finding the `=` in your string and then chopping out everything until the next whitespace, something like:

```
var = "SCF Done: E(RB+HF-LYP) = -107.450926197 A.U. after 5 cycles"
var = var[var.find("=") + 1:].strip()  # clean out everything before the equal sign
var = var[:var.find(" ") + 1].strip()  # clean out everything after the first whitespace
# -107.450926197
```

Or slightly more unsafe by splitting on `=` and then on space:

```
var = "SCF Done: E(RB+HF-LYP) = -107.450926197 A.U. after 5 cycles"
var = var.split("=", 1)[1].split(None, 1)[0]
# -107.450926197
```

Or to do it with a simple regex:

```
import re

find_numbers = re.compile(r"-?[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?")  # find any number

var = "SCF Done: E(RB+HF-LYP) = -107.450926197 A.U. after 5 cycles"
var = find_numbers.search(var).group()
# -107.450926197
```

You should also consider loading your current results first, then writing to the same list as you iterate over your `*.out` files, sort that list and overwrite the `results.csv`.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help. Your method is definitely cleaner and more straightforward. I'm not sure what you mean with your last point about loading my current results first though. Could you clarify?

Comment: @cyphex - you keep opening and closing your `results.csv` for any `*.out` file you're processing, only to load it up whole in the end just so you can sort it out and write it to another file. What I'd do instead is to load up `results.csv` first, read the rows in memory, then append the processed `*.out` data to that list of rows and finally, after processing all of the `*.out` files, write everything down to `results.csv` as it is, then sort the list and write the sorted list to `sortedData.csv`.